# Configuring IIS 6 to run 32 bit asp.net applications on Windows Server 2003 64 bit

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis-6, asp.net, 32bit-64bit

I need to run php on on one of my websites but I need it to support 32 bit binaries.

If I run:

```
cscript.exe adsutil.vbs set W3SVC/AppPools/Enable32BitAppOnWin64 "true"
```

...all my existing asp.net 2.0 applications stop responding - I get a "Service Unavailable" error even after restarting services. This error remains until I set that flag back to false and restart the IIS service.

I seem to have the 64 and 32 bit versions of the .net framework installed, so I thought it would be able to run my applications as 32 bit processes.

Can anyone suggest anything that might get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIS 6.0 can run in 32-bit or in 64-bit mode, but not in both modes at the same time. If you want it to run in 32-bit mode, it will run *everything* this way.

This also means you will need to configure ASP.NET to run using the 32-bit version of the .NET Framework, because as soon as you switch IIS to 32-bit mode, it will be unable to load the 64-bit DLLs it normally uses on 64-bit systems.

More info here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/894435.